# Consider the probability of connecting the terminal vertices using Binary Decision Diagram with length constraint

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, boolean-algebras

#### Definitions

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E,p),p:E \to [0,1]$ where $V$ is the set of vertices, $E$ is the set of edges and $m=|E|$, and $p$ represents the probability that an edge functions.  A set of terminal vertices $T \subseteq V$ and length constraint $l$ ($l$ can also generalize to weight) are also given. Let $X_i$ be the binary random variable "state of the edge $e_i$ in $G$", defined by $X_i = 1$ if edge $e_i$ is operational, and $X_i = 0$ if edge $e_i$ cannot be used. $X = (X_1, \dots,X_m)$ is the random graph state vector. A state $x$ of $G$ is denoted by $x = (x_1,\dots,x_m)$, where $x_i$ represents the state of edge $e_i$. The associated probability of $x$ is defined as
$$
Pr(X=x)=\prod_{i=1}^m (x_i \cdot p(e_i) + (1-x_i)\cdot (1-p(e_i)))
$$

Let $G(x)$ be the partial gragh $(V,E')$ with $E' = \{e_i \in E':x_i=1\}$. $x$ is a **connected state** if all the vertices of $T$ belong to the same connected component in $G(x)$. Define the probability $p_{conn}$ of connecting terminal vertices as

$$p_{conn} = \sum_{\text{$x$ is a connected state}}Pr(X=x)$$

Let $E'' = \{e_i \in E'':x'_i=1\}$ , and $x'$ is a **critical state** of $x$ if $\neg\exists e_i \in E'', x' \leq x$, s.t. $ x'' $ representing $E'' \backslash \{e_i\}$ is still a connected state. Apparently, any connected state has at least one critical state.
$x$ is a **constrained connected state** if $x$ is a connected state and satisfies
$$\min_{x'\in \mathcal X(x)} \sum^m_{i=1} x'_i \leq l$$
, where $\mathcal X(x)=\{x':x' \text{ is a critical state of } x\}$ .
Define the probability $p_{constrained}$ of connecting terminal vertices with length constraint as

$$p_{constrained} = \sum_{\text{$x$ is a constrained connected state}}Pr(X=x)$$

BDD(Binary Decision Diagram) can be used to model the computation of $p_{conn}$ and $p_{constrained}$. A BDD node $x_i$ represents an edge, and the high edge from BDD node to another BDD node represents $x_i = 1$, as well as low edge from $x_i$ to another BDD node represents $x_i = 0$. Then we can compute $p_{conn}$ and $p_{constrained}$ by constructing BDD and traversing BDD.

#### Example for critical state

[example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnVxK.png)

In this example graph, $T=\{s,t\}$.
Let $x= (1,0,1,1,0)$, i.e. edge 1,3,4 functions and $x$ is a connected state.
So the only one critical state $x'$ of $x$ is $x'=(1,0,0,1,0)$, i.e. edge 1,4 are selected.

#### Question

There are some researches that can compute $p_{conn}$ considering $2 \leq |T| \leq |V|$ using BDD. But my question is that, is there any research that proposed some algorithms which studied $p_{constrained}$ using BDD? It is not necessary to consider the size of set $T$. Any $|T|$ is OK.  (I have searched for it but couldn't find it).

Any reply will be greatly appreciated.